# react - building a tooltip with createPortal without adding an element sibling to 'root'

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

i am trying to build a tooltip component with `ReactDOM.createPortal` to protect it from z-index and overflow bugs, but the issue is - the component will live in an external library and imported to different projects. therefore, i cannot add a div to render the tooltip into in the `index.html` file to write something like `ReactDOM.createPortal(<Tooltip />, document.querySelector('#tooltip'))`.

what are the possible ways on overcoming this? can i somehow dynamically create a div outside the `body` inside my component?

thanks a lot for all the answers!

Answer (score 0):

This is a very old question and you may not be still looking for answers, I just found out about React portals.

If the component is part of a library then your component should take as props both the tooltip and the DOM node should be passed as props I think.